# WPF - Jumpy/jittery slider control causing problems with "BringIntoView"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scroll, frameworkelement

I have a framework element that I need to keep in view at all times. To do this, I am using `BringIntoView()` whenever it gets out of bounds. However, I have noticed that `BringIntoView()` does not handle rapidity very well. When the UI is manipulated in a rapid fashion (in my case it is a timeline containing a selector), `BringIntoView()` seems to not be able to keep up. When the selector in the timeline is moved quickly outside the bounds of the container, `BringIntoView()` will (seemingly) try to anticipate this rapidity by moving the selector very far from the bounds.

Instead of a smooth scrolling effect that takes place when the selector is moved slowly, instead what we get is a jittery scroll with the selector constantly going back and forth between being at the edge of the container and in the middle of it. It is almost as if it cannot handle the rapidity and gives up trying to make precise movements by just chucking the framework element as far away from the container boundaries as possible.

I have no idea how `BringIntoView()` works but I'd like something similar that can anticipate the distance that needs to be scrolled in comparison to the positioning of the framework element. Is there anything else similar to "`BringIntoView()`"?

Comment: Did you try ScrollIntoView?

Comment: @ChrisW. the elements I'm using do not have ScrollIntoView, however I might have fixed my issue by changing when BringIntoView is being called. Edit: nope, nevermind.

Comment: I cannot move it because a lot of its properties depend on info in the UI. Its width, Canvas.Left position and Height all depend on things in the UI. I would just like to know why BringIntoView is acting out and how could I change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of searching I came upon this thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2d0d202b-caf7-4d71-a61f-bcaa33565cdd/jumpy-slider-control-behavior?forum=wpf

The solution to getting rid of the jittery/jumpy behavior in the slider had nothing to do with "BringIntoView()" at all but instead with the rapidity of the two-way value binding behind the control. Adding `Delay=1` to the binding got rid of any jittery behavior in the control. It essentially adds a 1 millisecond delay to the two-way binding allowing time for the UI to update accordingly.

There is one tradeoff; the UI is not as smooth due to the 1 ms delay. But it's a tiny sacrifice, at least for me.